# How to specify a locale to Facebook OAuth Dialog?

Tags: facebook, localization, oauth

I'm trying to get my users to log into Facebook using the [OAuth Dialog API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/). I'm talking about: `http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth`

How can I specify a locale (ex: "fr_FR") so that the dialog displays in the locale's langauge? I've tried using the obvious `locale=fr_FR` in the URL but that doesn't work.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/internationalization#:~:text=Note%20that%20this%20only%20applies%20to%20plugins%20and%20buttons%20that%20are%20directly%20integrated%20with%20your%20site.%20Dialog%20such%20as%20the%20Login%20Dialog%20render%20in%20the%20language%20that%20the%20person%20has%20picked%20as%20their%20native%20language%20on%20Facebook%2C%20even%20if%20it%27s%20different%20than%20the%20language%20you%20select.  here it say for dialog/oauth it uses language from user settings profile.  i tested it is true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page on Facebook requesting for the user to grant access for your application is based on the user's [settings on Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/editaccount.php?language). For defining the `locale` in non-iframe social plugins using the JavaScript SDK, you need to define the `locale` when loading the SDK:

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/**en_US**/all.js">

Comment: Not sure I get you. When I redirect the user to https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth he's not logged in so how can FB access his FB settings?

Comment: @urig logged into Facebook, not your site.

Comment: What if a user is not logged in to Facebook? And what if you are not using the JavaScript SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Im using FB Social provider + auth0 and had the same challenge.
[https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/internationalization#:~:text=Note%20that%20this%20only%20applies%20to%20plugins%20and%20buttons%20that%20are%20directly%20integrated%20with%20your%20site.%20Dialog%20such%20as%20the%20Login%20Dialog%20render%20in%20the%20language%20that%20the%20person%20has%20picked%20as%20their%20native%20language%20on%20Facebook%2C%20even%20if%20it%27s%20different%20than%20the%20language%20you%20select](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/internationalization#:%7E:text=Note%20that%20this%20only%20applies%20to%20plugins%20and%20buttons%20that%20are%20directly%20integrated%20with%20your%20site.%20Dialog%20such%20as%20the%20Login%20Dialog%20render%20in%20the%20language%20that%20the%20person%20has%20picked%20as%20their%20native%20language%20on%20Facebook%2C%20even%20if%20it%27s%20different%20than%20the%20language%20you%20select).  here it says for *dialog/oauth: *Dialog such as the Login Dialog render in the language that the person has picked as their native language on Facebook, even if it's different than the language you select.*
i tested it is correct

so does not matter what param locale you will pass it is goign to use language provided in user setting profile